# How to modify and replace shapes with different versions in Flash?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, shapes

I am new in Graphics and Multimedia Programming and I use Adobe Flash CS5 Professional V11.0 to edit and create some short flash movies.

I have an old flash movie which is created by older version of Flash (Macromedia Flash 10 or 8). This falsh movie needs modification because it has some typing errors.

I had a rendered Flash movie (.swf) that I converted to its original format (.fla) with its associated resources like Action - Button - Font - Frame - Image - Shape - Sprite using a Flash decompiler software.

I have edited the shapes which includes the errors by my flash software and save it using the available formats which are CS5 or CS4 which are only allowed in saving options.

I took copies of the old edited shapes and replaced them with new correct ones but when I publish the file to be in *.swf format or expert it to flash it did not work as they are not there at all.it may be a type mismatch but I downloaded and installed old flash software version (Macromedia Flash 8.0) to read and publish them but it gives file reading error and was unable to read or manipulate them at all.

I tried a program that replaces specific shape or all flash shapes but it did not see that also and it is used only with *.swf format.

Is there any way to convert or treat shapes in flash as text ?

I searched the web for that but most results coming talks about Shape tweening and I did not find what I want.

How I can change the mistakes in these flash shapes and leaving the other things as they are like the action script and the timeline used as I only want to replace these wrong shapes ?

what is the wrong in my way or what is the correct way to do that ?

Thanks for your answer and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompiling swfs doesn't always produce a Flash file that you can then recompile back into a swf.

Once you have your new decompiled .fla (and before you change anything) can you publish it? If you can then you can go through the library and edit the existing assets to change the typing errors. If not then you will need to re-build the fla as Mattias suggests, using a completely new file.

Is there any way that you can get the original source files for the earlier version? This would save you having to rebuilt it from scratch.

Comment: the *.fla file I had after decompiling is ok and can be converted and published into *.swf without any problem but also without correcting the errors so my question was how to make it works fine after replacing the wrong shapes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried what you suggest and what Mattis told but it did not work fine and I had to make a new flash movie other than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to copy everything to a new *(fresh)* flash file rather than working in the "re-created" flash file? Sometime that helps ...

Comment: I will try this way and I hope it works. Thanks for your answer.